# One Software to develop android/ios/bb/windows 8

Tags: android, ios, windows, blackberry

I am a beginner in mobile development. I want to learn any software through which i can create apps for android/ios/bb/windows 8. Is there any? Kindly guide me. I prefer Java based software

Answer (score 3):

The only kind of app that will work on ALL devices (supposedly) is web apps. It's not quite as true as some people think because different browsers handle things differently. I've never liked the idea, because I think it provides a worse user experience on all devices. Look at Facebook. They did a web app and everyone hated it. So the redid it as a native app (iOS is out and Android is almost there).

Just learn the languages you need to develop for a platform. Java 5/6 for Android, Java 1.4 for BB (I think), Objective-C for iOS, and .NET for Windows Phone 8.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/).

It allows you to share all your non-UI code across iOS, Android, and Windows. However, you still will have to learn how to use Xcode for iOS, ADT for Android, etc. I do need to mention it is done in C# not Java, but they are very similar and the transitions shouldn't be too difficult.

The site offers a [free trial download](http://xamarin.com/trial).

*Note the trial only allows you to deploy to a simulator, to deploy to a device you'd have to fork over the money for the full version.

Answer (score 0):

You won't find a single good solution for all of those.

- For iOS you need to use [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode).
- For Android you can use [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) along with the [ADT (Android Developer Tools)](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) plugin.
- For Blackberry you can also use Eclipse with the [BlackBerry](https://developer.blackberry.com/java/download/eclipse) plugin.
- I haven't done any Windows Mobile development but I imagine you will need [Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/whats-new) along with the [Windows Mobile SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsmobile/bb264327).

Both Android and Blackberry will be Java based.  Eclipse is written in Java, though I think you meant the apps when you said that you prefer Java based software.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many tools available, search in google for "cross platform mobile development frameworks" .I prefer **PhoneGap** and **Titanium Development Platform from Appcelerator**

But the above is not based on Java. You need to learn web technologies.

Check this : http://devlup.com/mobile/cross-platform-mobile-development-tools/2416/

Comment: I've messed with both PhoneGap and Appcelerator and it was more of a pain than it was worth. It also doesn't get you a whole lot because if you want to interface with pretty much any of the phone hardware (sensors, etc) you will have to write native code anyway. So you will have to learn all of the languages and some APIs then combine all of that with HTML and javascript. Not worth it in my opinion.

Comment: Its purely depends upon what kind of application we are going to develop.

Comment: i've never met a web app that had the same performance and experience of a native app. every time i use one i cringe.

Comment: Me too. "never met a web app that had the same performance and experience of a native app" .

Comment: There might be a reason on why even the spearhead of hybrid apps (Facebook) finally dropped that silly idea.